# Process of how do I spot the errors in this buggy code?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging

I have this code:

When I launch it, I am able to get numbers i = 0 to i = 10. However I know this is not the objective of the code as the objective is to reach into the Scanner. But the scanner does not seem to work? Am I making an error importing a file or is this to do with the code? I'm noob.

```
package buggyProgram;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BuggyProgram {

  /**
   * The main method of the program. This is where it all starts.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] saNames = new String[5];
  String[] saNumbers = new String[5];

  Scanner scIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        saNames[i] = scIn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        saNumbers[i] = scIn.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println("The number of " + saNames[i] + " is "
                + saNames[i] + ".");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like very much that you've asked about the "process of finding bugs" in your code, rather than asking experts here "what the bug is". I respect that. What development environment are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: You need to be using `saNames[i] + " is " + saNumbers[i]` you are using two of `saNames[i]` in your final printout. In addition, you haven't provided if you get any errors.

Comment: Hi guys!

SORRY for the late reply. I figured out my mistake and didn't check stack overflow. For those interested in the error, it is because i = 1. It should have been i = 0 because the above is i=0 and you want the program to start from the beginning as Elliott has said.

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays start at 0 (not 1), and you're printing the same array element twice (in your second for-loop). Finally, you could always use a debugger to help you determine where things are no longer working as you expect.

```
// for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) { // <-- to match your first loop.
    System.out.println("The number of " + saNames[i] + " is "
            + saNumbers[i] + ".");
}
```

You might also use formatted output (the [formatter syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)) like

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    System.out.printf("The number of %s is %s.%n", saNames[i], saNumbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: It'd also seem more logical to use `i < 5` instead

Comment: @Cole I agree that would be more idiomatic, but that's really personal preference in java.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things you can do to make it easier to debug is to make the input fixed between runs. If you change `Scanner scIn = new Scanner(System.in);` to this:

```
Scanner scIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("some-file.txt")));
```

Assuming that `some-file.txt` is populated with the appropriate input, then you can run the program multiple times without having to manually re-enter the input. In addition, the input is fixed, so comparing the output of different runs becomes more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm, that your code works, as long as you change your final output:

```
    String[] saNames = new String[5];
    String[] saNumbers = new String[5];

    Scanner scIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        saNames[i] = scIn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        saNumbers[i] = scIn.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println("The number of " + saNames[i] + " is "
                + saNumbers[i] + ".");
    }
```